# drawing confidence interval graphs (especially in minitab or e-view)

Tags: graph, statistics, regression, confidence-interval, minitab-16

I've made regression model with 4 variables. And I have gotten the following regression equation

$$ Y= 0.0761 - 0687X_1 - 3.46X_2 - 1.937 X_3$$

I calculated Confidence intervals for these four beta values by using Bonferroni methods. I got these beta values;

$-0.123461 \le \beta_0 \le 0.27596$

$-3.18842 \le \beta_1 \le 1.81442$

$-8.96 \le \beta_2 \le 2.04036$

$-3.435 \le \beta_3 \le -0.4389$

And then,I calculated Confidence intervals for these four beta values by using Scheffé methods. I got these beta values;

$-0.1685 \le \beta_0 \le 0.3207$

$-3.75314 \le \beta_1 \le 2.379$

$-10.20212 \beta_2 \le 3.28212$

$-3.773 \le \beta_3 \le -0.100704$

Now, I want to plot graphs for these beta values like that

[image]

but i cannot draw such a graph for each beta value. Please show me a way for this by using  minitab or by hand.

Note that I dont know how to use R. I only know minitab and e-view

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with R and ggplot2 as follows:

```
> x = 1:20
> y = x*5 + sample(1:10, 20, replace=T)
> ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y))+geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

Comment: I dont how how to use R. Can I use minitab or e-view ?